# How reliable is fcm in 2019?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, single-page-application

I make web app for restaurants. when client in restaurant on web page selects dishes, he clicks "order", and waiter will receive a push notificarion on his phone via fcm for web.  Will waiter receive all notifications through fcm for web? I need them to be delivered in 2 minutes maximum, can firebase fulfill my requirements? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, most messages will be delivered in under a few seconds, assuming the target device is active and has a good network connection.  In practice, there is no way to ensure the timing of the delivery of a message, as the network could be poor or missing, and the device could be in a battery-saving state the delays receipt.  If you want to increase the chances of the message getting to the device, use a high priority notification, as described in the documentation.